# Combine different spreadsheets of guests

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two different spreadsheets, one with people and if they are going to come to the event or not:

| Names: | "EVENTNAME": |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Yes |
| Jordan | No |
| Sara | Yes |
| Louis | Yes |

I also have another one where their food preferences are described, but it is ordered differently.

| Names: | Allergies: |
| --- | --- |
| Sara | Potatoes |
| Jordan |  |
| Louis | Lemons |
| Mike |  |

Is there any way to generate one with only the people that will come and their preferences, such as:

| Names: | Allergies: |
| --- | --- |
| Mike |  |
| Sara | Potatoes |
| Louis | Lemons |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can use a combination of FILTER, INDEX and MATCH functions. Try the formula below. Adapt the ranges based on your sheets.

```
=FILTER(E2:F5,(INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(E2:E5,A2:A5,0)) ="Yes")) & ""
```

[image]

Comment: This is what is needed! Is it possible to make it able to handle the possibility that one person isn't in the other list?

Comment: @Ludwiggle In that case you may use the formula: `=IFERROR(FILTER(E2:F5,IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(E2:E5,A2:A5,0)),"")="Yes")  &"","")`.  If the (main) question has been answered, please mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)